# Can I remove the "edge-cases" tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

This tag doesn't seem to bring any value. It's too vague and doesn't match any specific expertise field.

As there are only [9 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-cases) having this tag, I think I can do the work myself but I'd like to be sure there is no objection before I proceed.

Can I remove it ?

And after I removed it from all questions (I'll replace it with more specific tags when it's the only tag), is there something to do to have it burninated?

[image]

---

EDIT : Mission accomplished. I made the cleaning. Is there something else to do in order to not see those tags again ?

Comment: Looks like a meta-tag to me as [tag:edge-cases] alone cannot tell anything about a question. When you decide to clean the posts, can you please take care of [tag:corner-case] too :)

Comment: Aggreed. I'll do both tags if I have no objection in a few dozens of minutes.

Comment: I suggest to wait for a day before the cleanup, just in case any community member with an opposing view sees your post later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nobody answers and nobody objected I suppose it means

- the sweeping was OK and
- there is no administrative task to do after my cleaning.

Comment: Once you remove the tag from all questions, it should get automatically deleted within 24 hours (:

Comment: @todofixthis Thanks. You know you missed an opportunity to make an answer ? :)